# In Sitecore CDP, can I create orders using the REST APIs?

Tags: cdp

Using the REST APIS (or Interactive APIs) in `Sitecore CDP`, can I create an order? Can that order have an order item of any type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our 2.1 data model allows order items with any type to be created in the CDP. The REST API endpoint for creating order items has not yet been released for REST APIs.

Using the 2.1 data model order items can be created using:

1. Batch API: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/sitecore-cdp-order-item-data-model-for-batch-api.html
   or
2. ORDER_CHECKOUT stream event: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/send-an-order-checkout-event-to-sitecore-cdp.html

We do have a REST API for creating order items in the 2.0 data model. However order items in the 2.0 data model can only create orders with a restricted number of order item types. For details see our documentation for 2.0: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-0/using-the-create-order-item-function-in-sitecore-cdp-rest-api.html

Comment: links are no longer valid